# Python Paramiko scp.get() error

Tags: python, ssh, scp, paramiko

What I am trying to do is use [this](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py) module to do scp with paramiko. I have successfully ssh'd, and used the `put()` method to scp files *to* the remote location. My problem arises when I try to scp a file *from* that location using the `get()` method. It gives me this error:

`scp.SCPException: scp: user@flibbertygibbit.com:/home/username/myfile: No such file or directory`

Problem is that that path *does* exist.

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
def download(file):
    scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
    scp.get('/home/{0}/{1}'.format(user.get(),file), 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop')`
```

`user.get()` referencing a tkinter StringVar containing my username, `file` being the name of the file.

[Here](https://codeshare.io/cNihX) is the entire code, minus personal details, in case it helps.

Output of `ls -ld /home/username/myfile`:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 145 Dec  1 13:50 /home/username/job.alf`

Output of `scp user@flibbertygibbit.com:/home/username/myfile .`:

```
C:\Users\Me>scp user@flibbertygibbit.com:/home/username/myfile .
Password:
myfile                                       100%  145     0.1KB/s   00:00
```

Thank you very very much to anyone who can help me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What is the problem? 1) That the `/home/myfile` is the correct existing path and the SCP fail, when it should not. 2) Or that the `'/home/{0}/{1}'.format(user.get(),file)` should produce a different path (not the `/home/myfile`)?

Comment: The problem is that /home/myfile is the correct path, it exists on the remote server, and yet the scp operation errors. It is definitely being passed the correct path, it's just not working for some reason.

Comment: Well, to me, the `'/home/{0}/{1}'.format(user.get(),file)` looks like a way to get a path like `/home/username/myfile` (what would actually look like a correct path to me, rather than just `/home/myfile`).

Comment: Ok, more testing done. The error now outputs the path it thinks is nonexistent as `/home/username/myfile` and still errors. I have triple checked and it is definitely, for 100% certain, being given a path that is very very real.

Comment: 1) What paths did you successfully used for `.put`? 2) Does the download work with a command-line `scp` client? 3) When you SSH to the server, what does `pwd` command output? What does `ls -ld /home/username/myfile` output?

Comment: 1) I used the same path I'm trying to `.get()` from, `/home/username`.

2) So it does work from the command line, but only when I use a relative path. I'm on windows, and the drive letters in an absolute path ("C:\...") mess it up. I tried the python with a relative path as well, and sadly it did not change the error :(
\\
3) The `pwd` command, when I first SSH into the server, outputs `/home/username`. The output of `ls -ld` is:
`drwxrw-rw- 5 amz15 amz15 4096 Dec 25 00:21 .`

Comment: I've asked for `ls -ld /home/username/myfile`, not `ls -ld`. Can you edit a complete output of the `ls ...` into your question? Along with a complete output and syntax of the command-line `scp`? And fix the wrong path (`/home/myfile`)?

Comment: Done. Is that the right stuff?

Comment: Is the `username@server.com` the same as `user@flibbertygibbit.com`? Your inaccurate samples makes it difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it tries to retrieve a file from a path which doesnt exist. I would recommend to use os module.

```
import os
os.getlogin()
```

this will return the current user.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear -- the path does exist. That's why I'm confused. Could you explain a little how the os module would help in this case?

Answer (score -1):

i would like to re-open this case since i face the same issue.
i can copy A=>B but cannot B=>A. Failure occurs only in python, while scp in bash works fine in both directions.

Edit:
***scp.put()*** resolved the issue